# Allow Java method arguments to accept constructor paramaters

Tags: java

I'm trying to optimize a section of my code which requires an object array with constructor parameters in it. Is there a way to add that to the arguments of a method?

I have an array of objects called SongList in that array there are objects from the Song Class with constructor parameters:

```
songs[] songList = new songs[1];
songList[0] = new songs("Danger Zone", "danger zone.mp3", "Kenny Loggins", 3.33);
```

I also have a method that searches the array based on the category and the search query:

```
//Method 
public static songs[] search(songs SearchCategory , String Quarry){}

//Calling of method 
search = AudioPlayer.search("aName", "Kenny Loggins");
```

Songs class:

```
public class songs {
    String sName;
    String fPath;
    String aName;
    double sLength;

    public songs(String songName,
                 String filePath,
                 String Artist,
                 double songLength) {
        sName = songName;
        fPath = filePath;
        aName = Artist;
        sLength = songLength;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I could make the first argument of the code accept a constructor parameter like Name? This would allow me to cut down the overall length of my code as I wouldn't need to use a switch statement.

Search method:

```
public static songs[] search(String SearchCategory , String Quarry){

    //Returned array value
    songs[] ReturnedResult = new songs[0];
    // Method only list
    List<songs> SearchResult = new ArrayList<songs>();

    switch (SearchCategory) {
        case "aName":
            //for loop looks through all objects with the SearchCategory and places any found values into the list
            for (songs songs : AudioListing) {
                if (songs.aName.equals(Quarry)) {
                    SearchResult.add(songs);
                }
            }
        case "sName":
            for (songs songs : AudioListing) {
                if (songs.sName.equals(Quarry)) {
                    SearchResult.add(songs);
                }
            }
        case "fPath":
            for (songs songs : AudioListing) {
                if (songs.fPath.equals(Quarry)) {
                    SearchResult.add(songs);
                }
            }
        case "sLength":
            //Since the given quarry is a string and the length is a double the quarry is converted
            double QuarryDoubleTypeC = Double.parseDouble(Quarry);

            for (songs songs : AudioListing) {
                if (songs.sLength == QuarryDoubleTypeC) {
                    SearchResult.add(songs);
                }
            }
    }
    // Conversion of list to array for ease of use
    ReturnedResult = SearchResult.toArray(ReturnedResult);

    return ReturnedResult;
}
```

Comment: Class names should begin in uppercase, so they don't get confused with variable names, which start in lowercase.

Comment: You can use reflection

Comment: In addition to that @Progman said, class names are usually not plural unless you are modelling a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a concept of reflection in Java that you can use here.

1. You can use the `SearchCategory` to get the field value from the object
2. Then you can use it to compare with `Quarry`

**The working code is as below**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;

public class Songs {
    String sName;
    String fPath;
    String aName;
    double sLength;

    static Songs[] AudioListing = new Songs[1];

    static {

        AudioListing[0] = new Songs("Danger Zone", "danger zone.mp3", "Kenny Loggins", 3.33);
    }

    public Songs(String songName, String filePath, String Artist, double songLength) {
        sName = songName;
        fPath = filePath;
        aName = Artist;
        sLength = songLength;
    }

    public static Songs[] search(String SearchCategory, String Quarry) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        // Returned array value
        Songs[] ReturnedResult = new Songs[0];
        // Method only list
        List<Songs> SearchResult = new ArrayList<Songs>();

        for (Songs song : AudioListing) {
            Field field = Songs.class.getDeclaredField(SearchCategory);
            String fieldValue = (String) field.get(song);
            if (fieldValue.equals(Quarry)) {
                SearchResult.add(song);
            }
        }

        // Conversion of list to array for ease of use
        ReturnedResult = SearchResult.toArray(ReturnedResult);

        return ReturnedResult;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Songs [sName=" + sName + ", fPath=" + fPath + ", aName=" + aName + ", sLength=" + sLength + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        //Calling of method
        Songs[] results = Songs.search("aName", "Kenny Loggins");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
    }
}
```

This explains how it can be achieved you can further enhance your code after further exploring in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent opportunity to leverage higher-order functions.

In Java, these are realized via [Functional Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html#package.description).

You can reference the methods -- or fields -- from your `Song` class (which should be capitalized and singular, not `songs`) itself via `Songs::aName`. Furthermore, if you are trying to *find* a value, leveraging [`Predicate<Song>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) is an excellent idea.

Also, using [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) instead of arrays is advisable.

In short, your code could easily look like this:

```
class AudioPlayer {
    List<Song> audioListings = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Song song) { audioListings.add(song); }

    public List<Song> search(Predicate<Song> predicate) {
        return audioListings.stream()
            .find(predicate)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
// fill with songs 
player.add(new Song("Danger Zone", "danger zone.mp3", "Kenny Loggins", 3.33));
// find song with a specific aName
var songs = player.search(song => song.aName.equals("Kenny Loggins"));
```

The added benefit is that you can search for very complex things by constructing more complex predicates:

```
// find song with specific aName AND shorter then a given length
Predicate<Song> query = 
    song => song.aName.equals("Kenny Loggins")
        .and(song => song.sLength <= 3.5);
var songs = player.search(query);
```

I would advise *against* using reflection for this. Reflection comes with a whole range of problems and it simply isn't needed. The approach I have outlined above is far more idiomatic Java since Java 8, scales better, is easier to read, less error-prone and overall cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is a bit advanced; it's the interface `Function<Song, String>`. This will allow you to provide some transformation that selects a string value for your `Song` object, particularly in this case such options as `Song::getSName`. This is how it would be done with streams (and collections):

```
songList.stream()
  .filter(song -> quarry.equals(function.apply(song)))
  .findAll();
```

However, I strongly recommend that you become more familiar with the basics of Java before diving into more complicated logic, especially standards about naming (classes should be capitalized; variables should not), collections (lists are usually preferred over arrays), static vs. instance members, and interfaces.